# SQL Project using a where clause

Tags: sql-server, database, subquery, where-clause

So this is what I am working with new to sql and still learning been stuck on this for a few days now. Any advice would be appreciated I attached the image of the goal I'm trying to achieve

[OrderItem And Product Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMj0H.png)
[Order And OrderItem Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gy7kt.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdbMT.png)

Scenario:  Our boss would like to see the OrderNumber, OrderDate, Product Name, UnitPrice and Quantity for products that have TotalAmounts larger than the average

Create a query with a subquery in the WHERE clause.  OrderNumber, OrderDate and TotalAmount come from the Order table.   ProductName comes from the Product table.  UnitPrice and Quantity come from the OrderItem table.

This is the code I came up with but it causes product name to run endlessly and displays wrong info.

```
USE TestCorp;
SELECT DISTINCT OrderNumber, 
       OrderDate, 
       ProductName, 
       i.UnitPrice, 
       Quantity, 
       TotalAmount
FROM [Order], Product 
JOIN OrderItem i ON Product.UnitPrice = i.UnitPrice
WHERE TotalAmount < ( SELECT AVG(TotalAmount)
                      FROM [Order] 
                     )
ORDER BY TotalAmount DESC;
```

Comment: Your join makes no sense.  how does order relate to order item?  how does product relate to item  on price?  That's insane.  What are the PK/FK relationshipd between product, order and order item.  As it stands you dont' show now order item releates to order.

Comment: You should read [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) and update the question

Comment: Like I stated this is my first SQL class ever 0 knowledge and I'm still trying to understand and utilize SQL.

Comment: Yeah... I started off on the wrong foot sorry about that...   We need to know how product relates to order item.  How Order relates to order item.  What are the PK/FK relationships?

Comment: Order ID is a foreign key in OrderItem

Comment: this doesn't look like mysql are you sure that you are not using sql server?

Comment: Ya sorry is sql server. Also I Attached the tables in the post.

Comment: I interpert your table image to mean: Order.ID = OrderITem.OrderID  and 1 order can have many order items.  OrderITem.ProductID = P.ID and each order item ties to one and only one ID in product table.

Comment: Thank you guys xQbert got it I appreciate the help sorry my codes are so sloppy still learning all the clauses and queries. Promise next question will be more precise and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Best guess assuming joins and fields not provided.

```
SELECT O.OrderNumber, O.orderDate, P.ProductName, OI.UnitPrice, OI.Quantity, O.TotalAmount
FROM [Order] O
INNER JOIN OrderItem OI
 on O.ID = OI.orderID
INNER JOIN Product P 
 on P.ID= OI.ProductID
CROSS JOIN (SELECT avg(TotalAmount) AvgTotalAmount FROM [Order]) z
WHERE O.TotalAmount > z.AvgTotalAmount
```

Notes:

- You're mixing join notations don't use `,` and inner join together that's mixing something called ANSI Standards.
- I'm not sure why you have a cross join to product to begin with
- You don't specify how to join Order to order item.
- It seems very odd to be joining on Price....  join on order ID or productID maybe?
- you could cross join to an "Average" result so it's available on every record.  (I aliased this inline view "Z" in my attempt)
- so what the above does is include all Orders.  and for each order, an order item must be associated for it to be included.  And then for each order item, a productid must be included and related to a record in product.  If for some reason an order item record doens't have a related entry in product table, it gets excluded.
- I use a cross join to get the average as it's executed 1 time and applied/joined to every record.
- If we use the query in the where clause it's executed one time for EVERY record (unless the DB Engine optimizer figures it out and generates a better plan)

I Assume

- Order.ID relates to OrderItem.OrderID
- OrderItem.productID relates to Product.ID
- Order.TotalAmount is what we are wanting to "Average" and compare against
- Every Order has an Order Item entry
- Every Order Item entry has a related product.

Comment: I have tried this and I get incorrect syntax near Z and order.

Comment: Cross join was missing a open (.... corrected.

Comment: NOte we still need to know how product relates to order item.

Comment: Ok trying to add the snip of them tables as well.

Comment: Update SQL based on table image PK/FK  and ask questions, we want you to understand

Comment: You are a genius honestly appreciate this so much Ive been watching vid after vid and reading my book and couldn't achieve it.

Comment: again ask questions. if you have them I'd rather you understand why something works than it go unasked.

Comment: I appreciate it a lot been stuck on this for four days.

Comment: Always double check results and consider "Edge cases" to ensure your needs are being met.    We're not perfect and we can misunderstand the requirements.